# Convert spark sql to pyspark dataframe API for one query

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Below is the query to be changed to pyspark dataframe

```sql
SELECT b.se10,
       b.se3,
       b.se_aggrtr_indctr,
       b.key_swipe_ind
FROM
  (SELECT se10,
          se3,
          se_aggrtr_indctr,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SE10
                             ORDER BY se_aggrtr_indctr DESC) AS rn,
          key_swipe_ind
   FROM fraud_details_data_whole
   GROUP BY se10,
            se3,
            se_aggrtr_indctr ,
            key_swipe_ind) b
WHERE b.rn<2
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use [`spark.sql`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SQLContext.sql):

```py
sql_statement = """SELECT b.se10,
       b.se3,
       b.se_aggrtr_indctr,
       b.key_swipe_ind
FROM
  (SELECT se10,
          se3,
          se_aggrtr_indctr,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SE10
                             ORDER BY se_aggrtr_indctr DESC) AS rn,
                            key_swipe_ind
   FROM fraud_details_data_whole
   GROUP BY se10,
            se3,
            se_aggrtr_indctr ,
            key_swipe_ind) b
WHERE b.rn<2"""

df = spark.sql(sql_statement)
```

Comment: did not want that.
wanted to check in dataframe only and not spark sql

Comment: @vashi I don't understand why. That's exactly the same result, and you already got the query.